# Getting MapKit animateDrop to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Helloall in MapKit I can't figure out how to get the animateDrop animation to run, I'm using 1 viewController with both CoreLocation and MapKit running on it.

I read that I need to make sure I have set a delegate from the mapview to self in viewDidLoad which I have done and also to make sure I am using MKPinAnnotationView to get access to the animateDrop property, which I think I have done also?
I'm building for iOS8 also.

Any help would be great

//I'm not showing all code just showing some of the related parts of code below

```
.h
//I do set standard imports UIKit, CoreLocation, MapKit etc
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
//I do set various properties related. CLLocationManager, CLLocation, MKMapView


.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.mapView.delegate = self;

MKPointAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.813186, 144.962979);
myAnnotation.title = @"My title";
myAnnotation.subtitle = @"My sub title";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
// If it's the user location, just return nil.
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

// Handle any custom annotations.
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
{
    // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
     //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

    if (!pinView)
    {
        // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;


    } else {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;

    }
    return pinView;
}
return nil;
}
```

Any help would be great